expo-updates being interpretted as expo-update
I am trying to update my expo-updates package but when I type npm install expo-updates or npx expo install expo-updates I get this error:
PS C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit> npx expo install expo-updates
› Installing 1 SDK 51.0.0 compatible native module using npm
> npm install
npm error code E404
npm error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-update - Not found
npm error 404
npm error 404  'expo-update@~0.25.27' is not in this registry.
npm error 404
npm error 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-10T14_09_03_575Z-debug-0.log
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at NpmPackageManager.runAsync (C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\build\node\BasePackageManager.js:41:42)
    at C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\build\node\NpmPackageManager.js:36:20
    at C:\Users\alexa\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\theo game\expo-evolveit\evolveit\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\build\utils\spawn.js:19:34

`Why does it think I am trying to install the incorrectly typed package expo-update?
I have tried npm cache clean --force but it did not change the outcome. Found no explanation online either.
